# Sub Query delimite in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to update a fields (e.g. *parent_id*) for a table called *product_category_parent*.

Here is the query I am trying to use:

```
update sub_category_child set name='Mobile Phones', parent_id = (select parent_id from product_category_parent where cname = 'Appliances')
```

but its returning the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

here is the database schema

```
table product_category_parent
id              cname
-----          ----------
1              Electronics

table sub_category_child
id         name        parent_id
-----      --------    -------------
1          Mobile Phone   1
```

parent_id as foreign key to  product_category_parent.id

Comment: please `describe` relevant tables.

Comment: ok let me edit the question

Comment: Does `select parent_id from product_category_parent where cname = 'Appliances'` produce more than 1 record?  2nd.  You want all records in Sub_category_Child to have a name of 'Mobile Phones' with a parent_ID equal to parent ID from product_Category_parent where it's cname = 'Appliances'?

Comment: yes it do produce more than 1 records

Comment: oops my fault I want to have only one row affected that will change the product id

Comment: That's a problem.  Sub_category_Child.parent_ID can only be set to 1 value not X.  do you want the max or min parent_ID or do you need to correlate the update somehow?

Comment: i just want to change the parent_id of table Sub_category_Child

Comment: update sub_category_child set name='Mobile Phones', parent_id = (SELECT parent_id from product_category_parent where cname = 'Appliances') where id = 1; 

will this work?

Comment: I tried your query and didn't get a syntax error. Are you sure you copied it accurately?

Comment: try this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eea0a/1. you should add a constraint which child item you want to update.

Comment: Are you setting `parent_id` in all rows to the same value?  Does the subquery return exactly one value?

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably want the `id` from the parent table, not the `parent_id` from the parent table, right?

```
UPDATE sub_category_child 
SET name = 'Mobile Phones', 
parent_id = (SELECT id FROM product_category_parent WHERE cname = 'Appliances')
```

Second, with this query, you will update **all the records** in `sub_category_child` table. Is that what you want, or are you missing a `WHERE` clause?

Third, if the sub query returns more than 1 record, you have a problem.
You wither want to choose which one to use for the update (e.g. `ORDER by xx LIMIT 1`), or more likely - something is wrong. 
I assume each line in `sub_category_child` should only have one parent, so what's the real condition to find the parent for the `Mobile Phones` category?

Comment: He got a syntax error. Changing the column name won't fix that.

Comment: yes i'm missing a where clause I only want one row to update its parent id.

Comment: I tried your query but still getting a syntax error
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: hey I just tried running above query using php and mysqli that worked fine 
but in phpmyadmin sql query it returns a syntax error can you explain this to me I am very confused.